# Chrome - Set a custom proxy for all sites except certain ones

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

I'd like to set a custom proxy for Chrome - that is, not my Windows system Proxy, but a proxy just for this chrome session.

I can't figure out how to do that with Chrome alone, but i was able to do it with the Local Proxy Toolbar.

However, I need to be able to say "Use the proxy for all sites except *this one*", and I can't seem to do that, neither with chrome or local proxy toolbar.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A Chrome extension like "Proxy Helper" will do the trick

You define your windwos systems proxy settings as per usual and afterwards go into the proxy helper options and define chrome's settings in there. You can add exclusions from the proxy in proxy helpers GUI.

It can be found here:
[Proxy Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-helper/mnloefcpaepkpmhaoipjkpikbnkmbnic/related?hl=en)

***EDIT 1***

The other method would be setting it up via the command line, I believe it then does not overwrite the system proxy settings, more information can be found here:
[Command Line Flags](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc)

Answer (score 0):

You just want to use the [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm?hl=en)

You can configure your proxy in the extension and can also add exceptions for the sites.

Don't forget to select the proxy configuration that you created before browsing.